# How can I disallow certain changes in Woocommerce order status?

Tags: php, woocommerce, orders

I'm trying to force a certain flow when changing the order status. Lets say that currently I have the following statuses and a customized order for them:

- 1 **Pending payment** (default)
- 2-A **Processing** (default) | 2-B **On hold** (default)
- 3 **Ready for shipment** (custom status)
- 4 **Completed** (default)

Aside I have Canceled (default), Failed (default), and Refunded (default). But these are irrelevant for this matter.

Now, sometimes orders are created manually, and so I would like to avoid the rush of creating the order directly on Ready for Shipment or Completed status as this results in inventory not being reduced.

Order status should move forward only in this order:

- **Pending payment** when created.
- **Pending payment** to **Processing | On hold**
- **Processing | On hold** to **Ready for shipment**
- **Ready for shipment** to **Completed**

Backwards flow does not need to respect this.

Is this possible?

Comment: there is one action filter wc_order_statuses use by woocommerce which we can overwrite and maniplulate as per our requirement so you can try this accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Janki, searching about wc_order_statuses I found an answered question that achieves what I was looking for: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64439917/hide-order-statuses-in-dropdown-based-on-order-status-in-woocommerce-edit-order